# Fetching data from a database

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I am fetching data from the database using Entity Framework and Linq queries. I am wondering about the performance of getting data. I just want to check whether or not a `well` exists in the database. The database table has 15 columns and the number of rows are unknown.

```
internal static bool WellExists(string name, DatabaseContext context)
{
    var name = context.Wells.Where(w => w.name == name).Select(w => w.name).FirstOrDefault();
    return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseUwi);
}
```

Here my point of concern is the line in which I am using Linq queries. In this I am using a `Where`, then `Select` and then `FirstOrDefault`. Another solution is using `FirstOrDefault` only.

```
var well = context.Wells.FirstOrDefault(w => w.name == name);
return !(well == null);
```

The first query will get only selected data (`Select`) which is not required. Which solution's performance is better?

Comment: I suggest perhaps profiling the query and seeing what the underlying SQL is.  LinqPad is quite good for this, or I believe you should be able to see the SQL in debugger.  In spite of that I think you will find all your examples generate the same underlying SQL

Comment: If you want to know the performance of something **measure it and then you'll know**.  This question is like saying "I have a horse, does anyone know how fast it runs?"  How should we know?  If you have two horses and want to know which is faster, *race them*, don't ask strangers on the internet which one will win the race.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can try the `.Any` function on IQueryable. It is made for checking if there are any records.

Remember that `.Any()` has an overload that takes an expression, making the solution

```
internal static bool WellExists(string name, DatabaseContext context)
{
    return context.Wells.Any(x => x.Name == name);
}
```

I'm going to add a comment about your code as well.
In the second example you have `return !(well == null)`. This obfuscates the meaning of the code a bit, and would be clearer if you write `return well != null;`